# Is HTML Regex The Same As JS Regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

In HTML, the pattern="" attribute allows regex. However, I can't find a list of HTML regex parameters. Thus, I'm wondering if it's the same as JS.

Comment: What do you mean by "commands"?

Comment: *The regular expression language is the same as the JavaScript RegExp algorithm, with the 'u' parameter that makes it treat the pattern as a sequence of unicode code points. The pattern is not surrounded by forward slashes.* from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Comment: `pattern` regex is parsed with JS regex engine.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, bad terminology on my end. Is "tags" suitable?

Comment: @Quentin I changed it to "parameters" now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, from the [docs for `pattern`  attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

> A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. The pattern must match the entire value. Use the title attribute to describe the pattern to help the user. This attribute only applies when the value of the type attribute is text, search, tel, url, email, or password. **The regular expression language is the same as the JavaScript RegExp algorithm**, with the 'u' parameter that makes it treat the pattern as a sequence of unicode code points. The pattern is not surrounded by forward slashes.

Emphasis mine

Answer (score 3):

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-pattern

If specified, the attribute’s value must match the JavaScript Pattern production. [ECMA-262]

Answer (score 2):

It is properly specified on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

> The regular expression language is the same as the JavaScript RegExp algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the implementation of Regular expression in many Programming language follow at a certain limit the **Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE)** convention.

So if you have some regular expression write in any language which follow the PCRE you can use the same regular expression in any other language which did the same thing to make the same pattern matching

Comment: Ah, good to know! I've learned Perl Regex already, and I can immediately see the similarity!

Comment: That means you already know how to write regular expression in Javascript and in many other  programming languages